# Convert UTC time to custom time zone with boost

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, timezone

I'm trying to convert a UTC time to a custom time zone. I've read a lot of questions about it here and there but they all seem to do the opposite, or to use a time adjustor where you can't set the timezone. So far here what I've managed to do:

```
 boost::local_time::time_zone_ptr           time_zone(new boost::local_time::posix_time_zone("EST5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0"));
 boost::posix_time::ptime const             now(boost::gregorian::date(2004,11,5), boost::posix_time::hours(10));
 boost::local_time::local_date_time  const  ny(now, time_zone );
 //
 ny.utc_time().time_of_day();     // Expected: 10:00 Actual: 10:00
 ny.local_time().time_of_day();   // Expected: 04:00  Actual: 16:00
```

I want ny.local_time() to show be 04:00, because when UTC time is 10:00, it's 4:00 in new york.

Can anyone suggest the right way to do it ?

Comment: You really should avoid POSIX time zones.  See [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) which has a section on POSIX towards the bottom.  You should instead use IANA/Olson time zones, such as `"America/New_York"`.  Boost *sort of* has support for these, except they use [a hardcoded list](https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/blob/master/data/date_time_zonespec.csv) - which is outdated and strips away all of the history.  If you want to do it right, consider using [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boost library seems to interpret the "offset" as the amount to add to UTC to get the local time; while the standard POSIX convention is the other way round. Change it to

```
"EST-5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0"
    ^
```

Comment: It's weird because I had it from this website, it looks like they are all wrong: http://svn.fonosfera.org/fon-ng/trunk/luci/modules/admin-fon/root/etc/timezones.db

Comment: @jules: Looking more closely, I think it's Boost that got it wrong. According to POSIX, the offset is supposed to be the value to add to local time to get UTC; Boost has it the other way round.

Comment: Interesting, are you sure about that? I am now using a posix timezone string generated using the csv database provided. It looks like that: `EST-05EDT+01,M4.1.0/02:00,M10.5.0/02:00` and it works as expected.

Comment: @jules: Not 100% sure, since I don't have a copy of the POSIX standard.  But certainly the [linux `TZ` format](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tzset) "specifies the time value to be added to the local time to get Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)", the opposite to Boost's convention.